# Permission Denied - \tmp\hive in sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, rstudio, sparklyr

I am trying to copy R dataframe to Spark 2.0.1 using **copy_to** function but it says

> The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rw-rw-rw-

I executed **winutils.exe** to change the permissions but still I get the same Exception of permissions.

```
%HADOOP_HOME%\bin\winutils.exe chmod 777 \tmp\hive
```

I tried other variants of the command like -

```
%HADOOP_HOME%\bin\winutils.exe chmod 777 C:\tmp\hive
%HADOOP_HOME%\bin\winutils.exe chmod 777 /tmp/hive
%HADOOP_HOME%\bin\winutils.exe chmod 777 -R \tmp\hive
```

but nothing worked. I still get the error

Comment: By which are you facing issue in writing hdfs temo dir?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried using advanced permission and all my permissions were set to **rwx**. I tried running `ls -l` command but was getting an error;

```
C:/> %HADOOP_HOME%/bin/winutils ls C:/tmp/hive
FindFileOwnerAndPermission error (1789): The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed.
```

My system was unable to connect to it's domain controller so I had to connect to VPN and then execute `C:/> %HADOOP_HOME%/bin/winutils chmod 777 /tmp/hive`.

It worked!

Comment: greetings dude, which vpn did you connected?