# Spark installation issue: Error while instantiating org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder

Tags: python, apache-spark, hive, installation, pyspark

I followed all environment variable and installation instructions of Spark. Now when I run `pyspark`, I get following error:

> pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: u"Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder':"

[image]

I have already added the PATH, HADOOP_HOME, SPARK_HOME, along with winutil.exe file. Also tried one of the solutions posted on web for above error saying to change permissions like this

```
C:\winutils\bin>winutils.exe chmod 777 \tmp\hive
```

Nothing worked.

As you can see above, spark does start but nothing else works. See below when I enter following command:

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: After 5 hours of search! Found it!!! All you need to do is connect to a VPN and then change permissions in winutils.exe \tmp\hive as done in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42784127/permission-denied-tmp-hive-in-sparklyr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming windows environment) check and set for the permission as given below.

```
C:\spark\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\bin>%HADOOP_HOME%\bin\winutils.exe ls \tmp\hive
drwx------ 1 BUILTIN\Administrators CORP\Domain Users 0 Oct 13 2017 \tmp\hive

C:\spark\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\bin>%HADOOP_HOME%\bin\winutils.exe chmod 777 \tmp\hive

C:\spark\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\bin>%HADOOP_HOME%\bin\winutils.exe ls \tmp\hive
drwxrwxrwx 1 BUILTIN\Administrators CORP\Domain Users 0 Oct 13 2017 \tmp\hive
```

Comment: Remember to use the correct version of winutils for the version of OS you are running (extrememly important):
64bit - https://codeload.github.com/gvreddy1210/64bit/zip/master  and 32bit : https://codeload.github.com/gvreddy1210/32bit/zip/master